# How to create a google cloud pubsub subscriptions with service account by terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-pubsub, terraform-provider-gcp

From this document, I want to create the same thing by terraform.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions create myRunSubscription --topic myRunTopic \
   --push-endpoint=SERVICE-URL/ \
   --push-auth-service-account=cloud-run-pubsub-invoker@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

terraform's main.tf

```
resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "my_task" {
  name  = "my-task-subscription"
  topic = google_pubsub_topic.my_task.name

  ack_deadline_seconds = 20

  push_config {
    push_endpoint = var.push_endpoint
  }

  dead_letter_policy {
    dead_letter_topic = "cloud-run-pubsub-invoker@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }
}
```

terraform apply

```
  # module.pubsub.google_pubsub_subscription.my_task will be created
  + resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "my_task" {
      + ack_deadline_seconds       = 20
      + id                         = (known after apply)
      + message_retention_duration = "604800s"
      + name                       = "my-task-subscription"
      + path                       = (known after apply)
      + project                    = (known after apply)
      + topic                      = "MyTask"

      + dead_letter_policy {
          + dead_letter_topic = "cloud-run-pubsub-invoker@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
        }

      + expiration_policy {
          + ttl = (known after apply)
        }

      + push_config {
          + push_endpoint = "https://an-endpoint.com"
        }
    }
```

Got error:

```
Error: Error creating Subscription: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid resource name given (name=cloud-run-pubsub-invoker@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com). Refer to https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#resource_names for more information.
```

From the terraform's document, `dead_letter_policy` is related to Pub/Sub service account:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/pubsub_subscription#dead_letter_policy

But why it doesn't work? How to set `--push-auth-service-account` as google official then?

Comment: Have you set your IAM subscription policies using `pubsub_subscription_iam`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
  dead_letter_policy {
    dead_letter_topic = "cloud-run-pubsub-invoker@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  }
```

You are trying to assign a service account identity to `dead_letter_topic`. That is incorrect.

Instead use something like this to create a topic:

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "example_dead_letter" {
  name = "example-topic-dead-letter"
}
```

Or this to reference an existing topic:

```
data "google_pubsub_topic" "example_dead_letter" {
  name = "example-topic-dead-letter"
}
```

and then use that resource like this:

```
  dead_letter_policy {
    dead_letter_topic = google_pubsub_topic.example_dead_letter.id
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Terraform document you linked said as below.

> The Cloud Pub/Sub service account associated with this subscription's
> parent project (i.e.,
> service-{project_number}@gcp-sa-pubsub.iam.gserviceaccount.com) must
> have permission to Acknowledge() messages on this subscription.

It seems that your service account you use for dead letter policy doesn't have appropriate permission to acknowledge messages.

According to IAM document, It needs at least *pub/sub subscriber* role to acknowledge messsages.

Refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#pub-sub-roles) to get more info about pubsub roles.